# Error when switching weapon while loading bullet in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have some guns for one player in Unity. I try to switch between them using the number keys (1, 2, ... 9). Here is what I'm doing:

```
nextWeapon = GetNumberInput();
if (nextWeapon >= 0 && nextWeapon < weapons.Length)
{
    // i want to do something here to reset the current weapon before Active nextWeapon 
    // (e.x: current weapon is still loading, it needs to be stop loading and be NORMAL)

    weapons[currWeapon].SetActive(false);
    weapons[nextWeapon].SetActive(true);
    currWeapon = nextWeapon;
}
```

But if my current weapon (1) is playing "Loading" animation like that:

[image: loading weapon (1) and press number key to switch to weapon (2)]

then I press key to switch to another weapon (2):

[image: here is weapon (2)]

and switch to weapon (1) again, the weapon is not normal anymore:

[image: what i get when i switch to weapon (1) again]

please tell me what i can do with it.

If I switch while shooting or running, everything is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is these animations (states) changes default structure of the gun. It turns out, all i have to do is uncheck `write default` in `Inspector` of all animations.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your animator is messed up when you change the weapon back again. You could reset the animator everytime you switch the weapon. Something like this:

Define "WeaponChanged" as a trigger.

Link: AnyState -> Idle (or however it is called in your animator) When "WeaponChanged" is Triggered

In code, whenever you switch the weapon:

```
nextWeapon = GetNumberInput();
if (nextWeapon >= 0 && nextWeapon < weapons.Length)
{
    weapons[currWeapon].SetActive(false);
    weapons[nextWeapon].SetActive(true);
    currWeapon = nextWeapon;
    currWeapon.GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("WeaponChanged");
}
```

I hope something like this may fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you, it must work when we reset the gun before deactivate. But there is another problem i have found that `    currWeapon.GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("WeaponChanged");
` don't have enough time do play the `reset animation` before deactivate. I found another solution for it, i showed it in an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a deploy animation for weapons that would play everytime you switch your weapon, that way it would reset your animator plus it makes the game more interesting. Max Play's code and animator structure would work for that.